# Significance of Guru poornima

Tags: guru, poornima

What are the benefits that one will get while praying Guru on this auspicious day? What are the steps to be followed  for praying? Can all the Lokha Gurus can be prayed on that day?

Comment: PS--I have found questions on guru poornima celebration not significance. Hence asked.

Comment: Related: [Which scripture says Krishna Dwaipayana Vyasa was born on Asad Purnima?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28409/12304)