# Which scripture says Krishna Dwaipayana Vyasa was born on Asad Purnima?

Tags: vyasa, poornima

It is believed that Vyasa was born on Asad Purnima. That's the reason Asad Purnima is known as Vyasa Purnima. But, which scripture says Krishna Dwaipayana Vyasa was born on Asad Purnima?

Comment: Related: [Significance of Guru poornima](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28405/12304)