# Is there any references about Vyasa's approx. birth century?

Tags: mahabharata, vyasa

There are a lot of references for Mahabharata war timeline, but I couldn't find much about Vyasa's birth century. Is there any reference(s) for the same?

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28409/which-scripture-says-krishna-dwaipayana-vyasa-was-born-on-asad-purnima